# How to display the Module name selected from the drop down menu

Tags: php

I have this code below in the "module.php" script where it displays options in a drop down menu of each ModuleId and Module Name:

```
 $sql = "
    SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
    c.CourseName,
    m.ModuleName
    FROM Course c
    INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
    JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
    WHERE
    (c.CourseId = ?)
    ORDER BY c.CourseId, m.ModuleId
    "; 

     $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

     $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$course);

     $sqlstmt->execute(); 

     $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);


    $moduleHTML  = "";  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
        $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$dbModuleId'>" . $dbModuleId . " - " . $dbModuleName . "</option>".PHP_EOL;   
    } 


    echo $moduleHTML; 

     $sqlstmt->execute();
```

Now I want to echo the ModuleId and Module Name on a separate page (editsession.php), now I have managed to echo the Module Id but my question is that how do I echo the Module Name in the other page?

```
    $moduleHTML = "";  
    $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
    $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
    $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {    

$outputmodule = ""; 
$outputmodule = "<p><strong>Module:</strong> " . $_POST['modules'] .  " - "  . "" . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a SELECT query based on your ModuleID.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by changing the select query based on ModuleId, it is already based on ModuleID int it?

Comment: You say you have managed to echo the Module Id. Then if you want to echo Module Name, you just have make another request :  `SELECT m.ModuleName FROM Module m WHERE m.ModuleId = %1`, with Module Id as %1. Have I missed something ?